# How can I use Acr.Userdialogs in a Xamarin.Forms UWP shared code project? Or any XF UWP project

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a project that until now has been XF (4.8) with iOS only. It started many years ago as a "shared code" project.  I've been using Acr.Userdialogs successfully in iOS.

Now I need UWP.  I've made good progress in half a day. But as soon as a pop-up would pop-up I get exception

```
"[Acr.UserDialogs] This is the bait library, not the platform library.  You must install the nuget package in your main executable/application project"
```

Many answers say to make sure I add the nuget to both the platform and the main project, but that is not how shared code projects are organized.  It's a bit late to change to another orientation now.

I feel I'm missing something obvious. I looked for an "Init()" method, but it does not seem to exist.  All I did was add the nuget in.  Is there anything more I shoud add?  Any line of code I need in App.xaml.cs

ADDITIONAL NOTE:  I just tried an empty project fresh from VS2022, and it is Xamarin.Forms 5.0.   I added Acr.Userdialogs to all projects.  I got SAME RESULT.  Code is simple enough:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("hi");
}
```

Does Acr.Userdialogs will work with UWP?

Comment: the docs clearly say UWP is supported.  However, the library ceased development in March 2021.  You probably need to update your Forms project to .NET standard - "shared" projects have been deprecated/obsolete for several years.  I'm surprised your iOS project still works.  You could also try manually referencing the ACR library from your UWP project instead of relying on nuget.

Comment: Thanks @Jason! You are right, I should transition to .NET Standard -- and I will.  But, I still have an issue -- when I created a brand new app which is .NET Standard, I get the same result in windows.  In fact, I got the same result when running the Android app, but added the Userdialogs.Init(this) call and it works.  So, I still think I'm missing some little thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the target version of your UWP application to windows 10, 19041.

Comment: I find this issue goes away if the Min Version is Win10, 19041.  Fails for 17763.